# Load DAG Params in Body of DAG

Tags: dynamic, parameters, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am to generate a set of tasks, dynamically using DAG Params. In details, I would like to "pass" a list of dates (string) to my DAG, and pass each date (string) to a sub-dag, that I trigger in a sequential fashion. In following, I use `DummyOperator()` instead.

in my DAG, I have:

```
...
with DAG(
       ...,
       params={"date_list":Param(["2022-10-10"], type="array", ...}
       ),
as dag:

    t0 = None
    for idx, _date in enumerate("{{params.date_list}}"):
        t1 = DummyOperator(task_id="f{idx}-{_date}")
       
        if t0 is not None:
            t0 >> t1
        t0 = t1
```

For instance, if I input, `date_list=["2022-01-10", "2023-06-22"]`, i expect to see two tasks generated, like following:

```
"0-2022-01-10" >> "1-2023-06-22"
```

Unfortunately, this code does not work since `{{params.date_list}}` does not get parsed, and passed as "{{params.date_list}}" instead.

What is the best way to achieve above, i.e., to dynamically generate tasks based on the input param? Any solution that help me to generate that list, and hence, use in the `for loop` is fine.

I appreciate if someone shed some lights for me.

UPDATE:
following @ozs comment, I made the following changes:

```
    def make_list():
        context = get_current_context()
        return context["params"]["date_list"]

    @task
    def generate_tasks(arg):
        return TriggerDagRunOperator(task_id=f"{arg}", trigger_dag_id="test_action", wait_for_completion=True)

    generate_tasks = generate_tasks.expand(arg=make_list())
    (generate_tasks)
```

and in other DAG, `test_action.py` i have only a simple `PythonOperatopr()`.

However, no secondary DAG is being triggered. Am i missing something?

Comment: Check for dynamic tasks. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use airflow dynamic task to create task according to list of params.

your code is running while airflow is parsing the dag and not running an instance of it.

to to that, you should use airflow [DynamicTask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5NVS.png)

at the example bellow I am triggering dags according the number of items I get in the date_list and pass each dag the value of item.

in this case I ran it with 2 dates so 2 dag_runs were triggered and each one I passed to date param(in test_action dag conf) the value of the item in the list.

```
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.decorators import task
from airflow.models import Param
from airflow.operators.python import get_current_context
from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator

with DAG(
        dag_id="test_dag",
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        params={
            "date_list": Param(["2022-10-10", "2023-10-10"], type="array",)
        },
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["test"],
) as dag:

    @task
    def make_list():
        context = get_current_context()
        return [{"date": val} for val in context["dag_run"].conf["date_list"]]


    test_actions = TriggerDagRunOperator.partial(
        task_id="test_action", trigger_dag_id="test_action", wait_for_completion=True
    ).expand(conf=make_list())

    (test_actions)
```

and the test_action dag :

```
with DAG(
        dag_id="test_action",
        schedule_interval=None,
        start_date=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
        params={
            "date": ""
        },
        render_template_as_native_obj=True,
        tags=["test"],
) as dag:

    @task
    def print_arg():
        context = get_current_context()
        return context["dag_run"].conf["date"]

    (print_arg)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: i used `TriggerDagRun` instead of print(args) however it doesn't seem to work, or at least it does not trigger the `test_action` DAG. I think I missing the concept here :(

Comment: task create a PythonOperator, so in your code you are creating an operator inside an operator. you should make the TriggerDagRunOperator without the task. what do you want to pass to the TriggerDagRunOperator? the date from params ?

Comment: correct. Each triggerDagRun with get a conf = {"date":arg}

Comment: TBH, I maybe not connecting to the concept here. im now confused on how the sequence of tasks can be creating following your method

Comment: The full explanation is in the link i added. The idea its to create number of task according dynamic data which you know only during runtime (for  example the number of items in the params list)

Comment: I updated my answer with TriggerDagRun